# "Carved from the living rock" — since when was rock ever alive?

Tags: etymology, figures-of-speech

According to Etymonline, *living* dates to the 14th century, and refers to

> "the fact of dwelling in some place," from O.E. *lifiende*, prp. of *lifan*

But we hear the phrase "the living rock" used all the time. For example, in George R. R. Martin's *A Storm of Swords*:

> Down a twisting passageway he went, narrow steps carved from the living rock, down and down.

I get that this is used in the sense of *dwelling*, as in the rock *dwells* in some place, but it still seems curious to me, even though I've accepted it every time I've encountered it in print my entire life.

Webster's 3rd New International Dictionary gives the expression "living rock" to mean

> remaining uncut or unquarried: NATIVE <in places the track was hewn out of the ~ rock — *Geo. Journal*>

That just regurgitates what we all know it to mean. But can anyone shed some light on where this was first used, or how it came to be such a standard trope?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My understanding of this phrase is that "living rock" refers to rock that is still part of the earth, like a mountain. Contrast this to a rock that has been quarried and moved somewhere; it is still rock, but no longer "living". So rather than building steps out of some material and placing them in a shaft or on a hill, the steps are literally carved into the planet itself.

Another way to look at it is that it's like a tree. You can carve things out of wood, but if you carve a living tree it's different, because the tree is still part of nature.

Comment: I haven't a sourced answer, but I think it is a metaphor from plants, as Mr Shiny and New suggests.

Comment: Works for me. I think you've cut right to the (living) heart of the matter with a few well chosen sentences.

Answer (score 15):

The phrase *living rock* itself refers to [rock-cut architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-cut_architecture), which is:

> the practice of creating buildings and other physical structures by carving natural rock

The Wikipedia article on the [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx) also mentions the term in context, saying that it is:

> rock that was present at the construction site, not harvested and brought from another location

So the fact that the rock was *living* means that it existed in some place--it was already living in the area that it was used. On Google Books, the phrase appeared by 1794, in [*Indian antiquities](https://books.google.com/books?id=5sxjAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA882&dq=%22from+the+living+rock%22&hl=en&ei=qrRNToamFOPiiAKB6-GRAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22from%20the%20living%20rock%22&f=false):

> [image: It was the peculiar delight of this enterprizing race to erect stupendous edifices; to excavate long subterraneous passages from the living rock; to form vast lakes; to extend over the hollow of adjoining mountains magnificent arches for aqueducts and bridges;]

It also was in use in 1785, in [Dodsley's annual register](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5VIAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=living%20rock&f=false):

> [image: we find there; and the digging them out from the living rock, of which they were a part, supposing the quarry to be upon the spot, is an operation, to which no mechanical powers, now known in the world, are equal, any more than removing them from the quarry to the place where they stand, at the distance of fifty or sixty miles.]

The Oxford English Dictionary lists several uses of the phrase *living rock*, under the following definition:

> d. transf.  (a) In various phrases of biblical origin. Of water: Constantly flowing; also, refreshing.  (b) Of coals: Burning, flaming. Cf. live adj.1 2  (c) Of rock, stone: Native; in its native condition and site, as part of the earth's crust.

The first uses of "living" to refer to rock is in the 1600s:

> 1697    Dryden tr. Virgil Æneis i, in tr. Virgil Wks. 203   In a spacious Cave of living Stone.

The OED writes also that this is related to the now historical definition of *live*:

> a. Of an element (element n. 1): naturally occurring, esp. in an uncombined state; native. Cf. earlier quick adj. 7a. Now hist.

This usage of *live* was first recorded in 1600. "Living" in the desired sense seems to have derived from this in the intervening years. So this may finally give a date to when this phrase was used: 1697, according to the most recent version of the OED.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning when the phrase entered the language and from where:

The phrase could be a translation carried into English from Latin. In Ovid's *Heroides* (Letter 6, line 88), Hypsiyle, among her many complaints about Jason's new girl, Medea, claims that she disturbs the natural order. She writes: “Illa loco silvas vivaque saxa movet” or “She [Medea] moves the forests and the living rock.” So while I don't know when it entered, I am guessing that this useful calque came into English some point around the Renaissance. The notion of *living rock* is at least 2,000 years old then. Does anyone know whether it exists before the Roman Imperial era in Greek or any other Indo-European language?

Answer (score 1):

It could be an allusion to many mythological figures. I know that in Greek, and many other creation stories man is carved from rock or clay. Earth and rocks are supposed to represent life and the idea of a living 'mother Earth'. It's a fairly common archetype in creation myths that life comes from mud, stone, or clay. So the phrase may be referring to rock as living because of how they are life producing so often.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who believes the earth as an organism (as in Gaia theory), the idea of rock as living is a no-brainer.  I believe that this term reflects an older and more holistic view of the earth than that of reductionist science.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).